# Is it possible to have a class feature with several values?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset in which the class has several values. For example, a dataset of face recognition where the class could be a tuple (man, old, Chinese).

Is it possible to have such data, if yes what ML classifier should I use?

Comment: Read about multi-label classification.

Answer (score 0):

```
I beleive this questions must be moved to another paltform like the https://datascience.stackexchange.com/
```

What you ask for is called [Mutli-label Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification)

In multiple label classification tasks, the model is trained to provide the probabilities or likelihood of more than one label for a given sample.

You can wether use the Multi-lable classification, or you can use multiple binary classifiers for the prediction of each feature. Like one binary classification for predicting Man or Woman, the other for Old or Young and etc. But you must be cautious that yoru labels be semantically mutual exclusive. I mean if you have labels like "sky" and "outdoor", the binary classification might be noisy if your labels are not carefully made. i.e if for a sample you have "sky" label, but no "outdoor" label, that will cause some noises during your training